# UIModalPresentationPopover bottom corners should not show background color

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller, cornerradius

Having trouble with a popover controller. A view controller is being presented as a modal popover. The arrow to the anchor point needs to be red so I set the background color:

```
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
vc.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor primaryColor];
```

The bottom corners of the popover are red from the background color.

**Edit 11/06**

When the vc is set to modal popover, the vc corners are being rounded by the popover automatically and the popover background is being exposed. But the rounding it does to the vc doesn't match the rounding of the popover.

[image]

This is unexpected. I can't find anything that exposes how to set the corner radius. I tried setting cornerRadius of view controller's view and collectionView to 0, but the corners remain the same and the popoverPresentationController still shows red. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: try to apply a mask for the last cell in the pop over to cover the red!!!

Comment: The popover controller seems to be masking the view controller's view and consequently the collection view inside it.

Comment: Im not sure how your view heirarchy is set up, but it looks like the red background is from your view, and your tableView/collectionView is not covering up the bottom corners of the view. Try not rounding the corners of the tableView/collectionView, or making it slightly taller than the view, so that it covers up the corners

Comment: When the vc is set to modal popover, the vc corners are being rounded by the popover automatically and the popover background is being exposed. But the rounding they are doing doesn't match. Is there a way to make the popover controller change the rounding of itself or my view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up subclassing UIPopoverBackgroundView to position and draw the arrow  and assigning its class to the popoverPresentationController.popoverBackgroundViewClass.

Answer (score 0):

In subclass of UIPopoverBackgroundView

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    for (UIView* subview in self.superview.subviews)
    {
        if (subview != self && subview.layer.cornerRadius > 0)
        {
            subview.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius; // cornerRadius - your custom property
            subview.clipsToBounds = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you can find better place instead of layoutSubviews.